# Navigate to last page on mvc telerik grid

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, telerik

How can you navigate to the last page of a telerik grid using javascript. My scenario is that I want to go to the last page of the grid in which the new record was added. I know I can use the 'pageTo' method in the Telerik Client API but I am not able to figure out how to count the number of pages a grid has. I was looking up if somebody was doing the same thing that I want to do and stumbled across this piece of code

```
var lastPage = ticketsGrid.totalPages(ticketsGrid.total);
```

But the value of the variable lastPage is infinity which is not possible as I only have 1 page in that grid.

Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the OnDataBound event.

You need to use a boolean flag which checks if this is the first load.

```
var firstTimeLoad = true;
    function onDataBound(e) {
        if (firstTimeLoad) {
            firstTimeLoad = false;
            var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
            grid.pageTo(grid.totalPages());
        }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks Emran H. answering. I moved away from that requirement. But I will surely use this if needed.